# Javascript sequentiality when using document.write

Tags: javascript

I have a doubt about the sequential order of execution of javascript in a special case, as follows.
A js file (`main.js`) included in the head of my page sometimes needs to include another js file dynamically, like:

```
document.write('<script src="userdata.js"></script>');
```

Within this second file is defined a variable `xmlFix`
However, if I try to reference this variable later on in main.js, it fails. Why? When is `userdata.js` executed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

for some alternative methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the following code:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>
```

<sub>a.js:</sub>

```
foo();
document.write('<script src="c.js"><\/script>');
bar();
```

<sub>b.js:</sub>

```
baz();
```

<sub>c.js:</sub>

```
qux();
```

The functions will be executed as follows:

```
foo();
bar();
qux();
baz();
```

This is because `a.js` needs to finish executing before the browser can move on to the next DOM element, which will be `c.js`, followed by `b.js`.

If you need code in `a.js` to use variables/functions defined in `b.js` or `c.js`, you will need to use a callback when the scripts have finished executing. For vanilla JS adding a callback to `window.onload` is a bit easier and more consistent than `document.readystatechange`, but the later is a little more performant.

If you're using the jQuery library, the "document ready" event is typically used (which should be along the lines of: `jQuery(function ($) {...code here...});`)

Comment: Thanks, you answered my question, foresaw my follow-up question ("what if I already had a `b.js` included after `main.js`?"), and answered that too!

Answer (score 2):

`userdata.js` would execute after the current script finished.  JavaScript does go in-order, but you're making a DOM change that needs to be handled.